# Create cursor from SQLiteStatement

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-contentprovider

I would like to use `SQLiteStatement` in my `ContentProvider` instead of the `rawQuery` or one of the other standard methods.  I think using `SQLiteStatement` would give a more natural, native, efficient and less error prone approach to doing queries.

The problem is that I don't see a way to generate and return a `Cursor`.  I realize I can use "call" and return a `Bundle`, but that approach requires that I cache and return all selected rows at the same time - this could be huge.

I will start looking at Android source code - I presume that "query" ultimately uses `SQLiteStatement` and somehow generates a `Cursor`.  However, if anyone has any pointers or knowledge of this, I would greatly appreciate your sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to use SQLiteStatement in my ContentProvider instead of the rawQuery or one of the other standard methods. I think using SQLiteStatement would give a more natural, native, efficient and less error prone approach to doing queries.

Quoting the documentation for `SQLiteStatement`:

> The statement cannot return multiple rows or columns, but single value (1 x 1) result sets are supported.

I fail to see why you would bother with a `ContentProvider` for single row, single column results, but, hey, it's your app...

> The problem is that I don't see a way to generate and return a Cursor

Create a `MatrixCursor` and fill in the single result.

Comment: Ah, I see, they have made SQLiteStatement very limiting.  So, that renders ContentProvider irrelevant to this question (I might not use it, but that's a different topic).  So, I'm now looking at the source for SQLLiteDirectCursorDriver to see if it's worth trying to override the bindAllArgsAsStrings.  That is really the crux of my issue - to bind the args properly and not run into problems where something is treated as text when it should be treated as something else.

Comment: Using rawQuery seems to work fine.  I saw a number of posts where people had trouble with comparing ints in the where clause, but I didn't have any such trouble (yet).  In fact, I think the arrangement is turning out pretty nice - I have a bunch of db wrappers in the "contract" file that isolates all the column names and db-specific stuff from the app.  Can post if anyone wants to use this an example.